# JS data-attribute for multiple elements with different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I code that shows a progress bar:

```
<span class="starsCount" data-length="64"></span>

<span class="starsCount" data-length="13"></span>

<span class="starsCount" data-length="33"></span>
```

and assigned bar length using [Jquery UI Progressbar Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/) by calling JS function in the way:

```
$(function () {
    $(".starsCount").progressbar({
        value: $('.starsCount').data('length')
    });
});
```

Now, I got an issue that all elements have the equal bar length of the first one
`data-length="64"`.  Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Code snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/hbLw34ec/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over each specific element and instantiate the `progressbar` on them individually. This allows you to access the `data` attribute of each element in the set using the `this` keyword. Try this:

```
$(".starsCount").each(function() {
    $(this).progressbar({
        value: $(this).data('length')
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hbLw34ec/1/)